# How to pass the vector data from c# to C++ and get the vector data from C++ to c#?

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio, vector, dll

I am new to C# and visual studio. I have wrote one function in C++.
I need to encapsulate C++ functions into dynamic link libraries(DLL),and then using C# to call C++ to operate vector data n parameters.

---

Here is my main function.

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <time.h>
#include <vector>
#include<iostream>
Void cal_lenth(double length,std::vector<int>length_par, std::vector<int> &length_final, std::vector<std::vector<int>> &bb_vec){
   //int length=100;
   //std::vector<int> length_par = {5,6,7,8,9};
   for (int i = 0; i < length_par.size(); i++) {
       length_final[i]=length_par[i];
       std::cout<<length_final[i];
       }
      std::cout<<std::endl;
   }
std::vector<std::vector<int>> bb;
   for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    bb_vec.push_back(length_par);
   }
   std::cout<<"endend"<<std::endl;
}
```

And here is my .h file:

```
#define IMPORT_DLL extern "C" _declspec(dllimport)
#ifndef PCH_H
#define PCH_H
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
#include <numeric>
#include <time.h>
using namespace std;
IMPORT_DLL void cal_lenth(double length,std::vector<int>length_par, std::vector<int> &length_final, std::vector<std::vector<int>> &bb_vec);
#endif //PCH_H
```

---

Here is my calling function "ConsoleApp1" for DLL files:
Now I compiled the code to DLL using newest Cmake and VS2022.I want to input the parameters(double length,std::vectorlength_par), and get the result in C#( std::vector &length_final, std::vectorstd::vector<int> &bb).

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using static ConsoleApp1.Program;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private double length;
        public class Vector
        {
            //private double length;
            private double[] length_par;
            public int Length_len => length_par.Length;
        }
        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct Length_par
        {
            public double length;
            //public Vector length_par = new double Vector();
            public double a;
            public double b;
            public double c;
        }
        [DllImport("pch.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        public static extern void cal_lenth(ref double length, ref Vector length_par,ref Vector &length_final,ref Vector &bb_vec);
        Length_par length_par = new Length_par();
        length_par.Add (1); //wrong
         
            
        //int result = cal_lenth(length_par);
        static void Main()
        {
            double length  = 100;
            //Vector length_par = new Vector();
            //length_par.a = 1;
            Vector num_par = new Vector();
            cal_lenth(ref length, ref length_par,out length_final,out Vector &bb_vec);

        }

    }
}
```

---

I tried to write a correct call file that was feasible when running a function without input and output parameters, but when I added parameters to the function, I failed. I have tried many ways to write call function,so my code is a bit confusing, and even my ideas are completely incorrect,I sincerely hope to receive your suggestions and corrections!Thank u!

Comment: Learn about C++/CLI and in general just copy data from C# to C++ unless you really want to know when you need to pin memory (using C# addresses from C++ can be tricky since the garbage collector can move memory around). e.g. [learn C++/clin in 10 minutes](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19354/Quick-C-CLI-Learn-C-CLI-in-less-than-10-minutes). The whole idea is that you first build a C++/CLI dll and use that from your C# code. Another option is to just write ALL the code in C#

Comment: You'll need to use arrays rather than vectors, you can't use c++ standard library types across the .net boundary

Comment: You should [`marshal`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal?view=net-7.0) a bulk memory to deal with it. Don't try to pass `std::vector` from C++ to C#

Comment: Thank u!But I have to use vector in C++ to transfer these parameters to C#,  if I cant reach the goal directly, I don’t know if there is a feasible solution ? (maybe write all code in C# only)

Answer (score 0):

As the comments said, avoid   using standard library types across the .net boundary.
Considering dynamic arrays are required and your example does not have specific C++ third party library, it will be more convenient to use C# code. Such as :

```
   static void CalLength(double length, List<int> lengthPar, List<int> lengthFinal, List<List<int>> bbVec)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < lengthPar.Count; i++)
        {
            lengthFinal[i] = lengthPar[i];
            Console.WriteLine(lengthFinal[i]);
        }
        Console.WriteLine();

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            bbVec.Add(new List<int>(lengthPar));
        }

        Console.WriteLine("endend");
    }
```